# form:select does not set the selected value

Tags: spring, forms, hibernate, model-view-controller

Basically I need a CRUD application for payments. Each payment is assigned to one account.

My jsp page shows the correct list of "account" objects but it does not set the selected account.

1. Question: How can I achieve a dropdown box with the assigned account pre-selected?
2. Question: The assignment (account to payment) works, but only with the below code in my PaymentDaoImpl.java (marked as workaround). Why is this the case?

PaymentDaoImpl.java

```
..
@Override
@Transactional
public int insertRow(Payment obj) {
    // Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    // !!!! workaround?? If I don't do this, account won't be assigned
    int accountId = obj.getAccount().getId();   
    Account account = (Account) session.get(Account.class, accountId);
    obj.setAccount(account);

    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    session.saveOrUpdate(obj);
    tx.commit();
    Serializable id = session.getIdentifier(obj);
    session.close();
    return (Integer) id;
}
..
```

jsp:

```
<form:select path="account.id"   >
    <form:option  value="-1" label="Select Account" />         
    <form:options items="${accountList}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="iban" />
</form:select>
```

Domain Account.java:

```
package com.beingjavaguys.domain;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Entity;  
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;  
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;  
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.*;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;


@Entity
public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String iban;

    private String bank;

    private String beschreibung;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getIban() {
        return iban;
    }

    public void setIban(String iban) {
        this.iban = iban;
    }

    public String getBank() {
        return bank;
    }

    public void setBank(String bank) {
        this.bank = bank;
    }

    public String getBeschreibung() {
        return beschreibung;
    }

    public void setBeschreibung(String beschreibung) {
        this.beschreibung = beschreibung;
    }

}
```

Domain Payment

```
package com.beingjavaguys.domain;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;



@Entity
public class Payment {


    private int id;


    private Account account;

    private float amount;

    private String text;

    private String comment;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = Account.class, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_account")
    public Account getAccount() {
        return account;
    }

    public void setAccount(Account account) {
        this.account = account;
    }

    public float getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(float amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }


}
```

PaymentController.java

```
package com.beingjavaguys.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.beingjavaguys.domain.Payment;
import com.beingjavaguys.services.AccountService;
import com.beingjavaguys.services.PaymentService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/payment")
public class PaymentController {

    @Autowired
    PaymentService dataService;
    @Autowired
    AccountService accountService;

    @RequestMapping("form")
    public ModelAndView getForm(@ModelAttribute Payment obj) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("payment/form");
        mav.addObject("accountList", accountService.getList());
        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping("insert")   
    public ModelAndView insert(@ModelAttribute Payment obj) {       
        dataService.insertRow(obj);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:list");
    }

    @RequestMapping("list")
    public ModelAndView getList() {
        List objList = dataService.getList();
        return new ModelAndView("payment/list","objList",objList);
    }

    @RequestMapping("delete")
    public ModelAndView deleteUser(@RequestParam int id) {
        dataService.deleteRow(id);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:list");
    }

    @RequestMapping("edit")
    public ModelAndView editUser(@RequestParam int id,@ModelAttribute Payment obj) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("payment/form");

        Payment paymentObj = dataService.getRowById(id);
        mav.addObject("accountList", accountService.getList());
        mav.addObject("paymentObj", paymentObj);

        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping("update")
    public ModelAndView updateUser(@ModelAttribute Payment obj) {
        dataService.updateRow(obj);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:list");
    }

}
```

---

Can you have a look on my implementation of the AccountEditor? I need the AccountService to lookup the account, or not? However, I don't get the service instantiated here..

```
public class AccountEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {
    @Autowired
    AccountService dataService; // == null ??

    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) {
        Account account = lookupAccount(text); // lookup account by accountId
                                                // text
        setValue(account);
    }

    private Account lookupAccount(String text) {
        int id = Integer.parseInt(text);
        return dataService.getRowById(id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a PropertyEditor implementation to convert from a String accountId to an Account object. Then in your jsp you use the path form:select path="account" instead of form:select path="account.id"

Implement a PropertyEditor as follows

```
public class AccountEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport{

   @Override 
   public void setAsText(String text){
      Account account = lookupAccount(text); //lookup account by accountId text
      setValue(account);
  }
}
```

Then register your AccountEditor in your controller

```
@InitBinder
 public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder){
   binder.registerCustomEditor(Account.class , new AccountEditor());
 }
```

With the above changes you wont need your workaround. Your solution is only setting the id property of the account and not the whole object

Comment: Can you have a look on my implementation of the AccountEditor?

Comment: Its perfect. To allowing for injection of the AccountService dependency then add your AccountEditor as a bean in your context and inject it into your controller

Comment: Thank you, this solved my second Question. I could not solve the fisrt Question yet.